# Python variable naming/binding confusion

Tags: python, variables, binding, python-2.7, scope

I am relatively new to Python development, and in reading through the language documentation, I came across a line that read:

> It is illegal to unbind a name that is referenced by an enclosing scope; the compiler will report a SyntaxError.

So in a learning exercise, I am trying to create this error in the interactive shell, but I haven't been able to find a way to do so. I am using Python v2.7.3, so using the **nonlocal** keyword like

```
def outer():
  a=5
  def inner():
     nonlocal a
     print(a)
     del a
```

is not an option, and without using **nonlocal**, when Python sees `del a` in the `inner` function, it interprets it as  a local variable that has not been bound and throws an `UnboundLocalError` exception. 
  Obviously there is an exception to this rule with regards to global variables, so how can I create a situation where I am "illegally" unbinding a variable name that is being referenced by an enclosing scope?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The deletion has to take place in the *outer* scope:

```
>>> def foo():
...     a = 5
...     def bar():
...         return a
...     del a
... 
SyntaxError: can not delete variable 'a' referenced in nested scope
```

The compile-time restriction has been removed in Python 3:

```
$ python3.3
Python 3.3.0 (default, Sep 29 2012, 08:16:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def foo():
...     a = 5
...     def bar():
...         return a
...     del a
...     return bar
... 
>>>
```

Instead, a `NameError` is raised when you try to refer to `a`:

```
>>> foo()()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in bar
NameError: free variable 'a' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

I am tempted to file a documentation bug here. For Python 2, the documentation is misleading; it is deleting a variable used in a *nested* scope that triggers the compile-time error, and the error is no longer raised at all in Python 3.

Comment: Okay, that makes much more sense, thank you. Agreed about the misleading Python 2 documentation in regards to this. The `name that is referenced by an enclosing scope` seems to imply (in my opinion anyways) a variable that is referenced in a scope enclosing the scope that you unbind the name in.

Answer (score 5):

To trigger that error, you need to unbind the variable in the context of the outer scope.

```
>>> def outer():
...  a=5
...  del a
...  def inner():  
...   print a
... 
SyntaxError: can not delete variable 'a' referenced in nested scope
```

Comment: Thank you very much, apparently the documentation is a bit misleading. This makes more sense.